# httpd respawning too fast, stopped

Tags: linux, apache

I just saw the following logs at my /var/log/messages file:

*Feb 19 16:25:01 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 rsyslogd: rsyslogd was HUPed

Feb 19 16:25:01 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd main process ended, respawning

Feb 19 16:25:02 domU-12-31-38-04-A9-92 init: httpd respawning too fast, stopped*

I was able to find some references at other forums (and also on this one) about this error with mysql, ssh and other services, but really didn't find any occurrence of this error with httpd process. What does it mean? What can I do to have it solved?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The issue happened again, and this time I was able to find some messages at the server logs. Even though the messages seems to be too generic, I'm pasting them here in case someone already faced this problem:

*[root@ip-10-196-193-155 httpd]# cat error_log
httpd (pid 1607) already running
[Mon Feb 24 14:07:22.146714 2014] [core:warn] [pid 1607] AH00045: child process 2257 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Feb 24 14:07:24.148902 2014] [core:warn] [pid 1607] AH00045: child process 2257 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Feb 24 14:07:26.151042 2014] [core:warn] [pid 1607] AH00045: child process 2257 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Feb 24 14:07:28.153170 2014] [core:error] [pid 1607] AH00046: child process 2257 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Mon Feb 24 14:07:29.154359 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1607] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down*

Comment: Check the server logs

Comment: I did, there's nothing there. Most people say this can be caused by an error at the configs, but the error is intermittent...

Comment: This second log part looks like an apache stop. maybe part of a restart, or triggered by a cronjob.

Comment: If you restart/stop apache, does the log files populated with the first kind of entries?